# Variadic template constructor and empty constructor?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have a class like the following:

```
template<typename ... TTypes>
class Composite {
public:
    //Composite() : null(true) { } 
    Composite(TTypes... values) : values(std::make_tuple(values...)), null(false) { }
private:
    bool null;
    std::tuple<TTypes...> values;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Composite<int, char, int> a1;
}
```

But this leads to an error because the second constructor would override the first one with TTypes = {}. Is there any way to keep the empty constructor?

Best,
Moritz

Comment: Use a single constructor with the parameter pack. It will also act as a default constructor.

Comment: Are you sure? I get the following error messages if I remove the first constructor:

StandardTypes.hpp:560:5: note: Composite<TTypes>::Composite(TTypes ...) [with TTypes = {Varchar<50u>, Char<1u>, Varchar<50u>}]
StandardTypes.hpp:560:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided.

And for me they make sense, because the second constructor expects arguments.

Comment: You obviously have more code that we can't see, so include the *full* error message and the code that produces it. Edit it into the question.

Comment: Squelching the first constructor will only deliver what you want if you create a `Composite<> obj;` If you want a `Composite<Some,Types,Here> obj;` that solution will not work for you

Comment: So if `TTypes` is empty, what do you want the constructor to do? Set `null` to true or false?

Comment: If the empty constructor is called, null should be set to true.

Comment: disable the second ctor from overload resolution [like here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7874b76605fdf2e1)

Answer (score 4):

Since none of the existing answers so actually solve the problem, but there is a [solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7874b76605fdf2e1) by Piotr Skotnicki hidden in the comments, I'm just gonna repost it here for visibility:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename ... TTypes>
class Composite {
public:
    Composite() : null(true) { } 

    template <std::size_t N = sizeof...(TTypes), typename std::enable_if<(N>0), int>::type = 0>
    Composite(TTypes... values) : values(std::make_tuple(values...)), null(false) { }
private:
    bool null;
    std::tuple<TTypes...> values;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Composite<int, char, int> a1;
    Composite<> a2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the following work around is an option for you:

```
template<typename ... TTypes>
class Composite : public ValueSet {
public:
    Composite(TTypes... values) { }
};

template<>
class Composite<> : public ValueSet {
public:
    Composite() : ValueSet() { } 
};
```

but it works.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for my main method. I cannot initialize a variable the following way:

    Composite<int, char, int> a1;

Comment: add an empty constructor to the first class. it is not in contradiction to the template constructor, because it will only create an `Composite(int, char, int)` constructor in the given example.

Answer (score 0):

The case where your parameter pack `TTypes` is empty makes the default constructor ambiguous. If you plan to provide at least 1 parameter, then you can specify an additional parameter:

```
template<typename TType, typename ... TTypes>
class Composite {
public:
    Composite() : null(true) { } 
    Composite(TType first, TTypes... rest) :
      values(std::make_tuple(first,rest...)),
      null(false)
    {
    }
private:
    bool null;
    std::tuple<TType,TTypes...> values;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Composite<int, char, int> a1;
}
```

However, take into account that this functionality is provided by `std::optional`, so it should be better using it.

```
template < typename... TTypes >
using Composite = std::optional<std::tuple<TTypes...>>;
```